# Joomla - create articles from a query on database

Tags: joomla

I am quite new at Joomla. I am trying to create articles dynamically from a table in the database. For instance, let's imagine I have a table that will point to text,image,..., I would like the content to display all (actually, with a modifiable query) articles to feed the display.

Do you know if there is an extension that would allow me similar things, or is there already something built-in?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: if you are willing to use an extension, why not simply add an article via the article manager?

Comment: well, actually it's because I have this table that is filled in another database by another software (like 'products' if you want) and I want to be able to query on this table, cast in articles and display it in the content display

Comment: There are a ton of forms extensions  that will let you do this. 
or you could just make a content plugin or there are a lot of other ways.

Comment: Would ou have some examples/names of the forms extensions?